# Removing wrong duplicate flag when there is a correct duplicate flag

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

In this question about destructuring JS variables [How does this syntax of 'let' work in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818952/how-does-this-syntax-of-let-work-in-javascript)

the question has been flagged as a duplicate of a question explaining how `let` works [What's the difference between using "let" and "var" to declare a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/javascript-let-keyword-vs-var-keyword) as well as this question that actually explains destructuring  [What does curly brackets in the `var { ... } = ...` statements do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290981/what-does-curly-brackets-in-the-var-statements-do)

The first flag is completely wrong, neither the questions nor answers touch on destructuring variables. It was correct to flag the question as a duplicate, but any user following the link wouldn't get an answer at all to the question.

Seeing as the question should remain closed I flagged it for moderator attention explaining the issue but it was declined.  Shouldn't it be removed? Is it wrong to flag issues like this for mod attention?

Comment: Who are you to say which is correct? Some folks voted for one duplicate reason, some for another; both should be shown.

Comment: @ssube That's not entirely accurate. It seems that *only 1* person (not including possible flaggers) chose the first post as a dupe target. It's quite possible for that one person to be wrong.

Comment: @ssube Well, the people who voted to close for the first either didn't read the actual question or lack competency to determine if it was correct. The correct reason was then added by a gold member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it wrong to flag issues like this for mod attention?

Yes.

Mods shouldn't be/don't act on flags based on technical inaccuracies which is what it would be if they decided that the post was a dupe of a different post than the one marked. What if the mod that happens to review the flag isn't very knowledgeable in the particular language/framework? Do you really want them making these decisions? No. The community has the tools to handle these things.

The correct thing to do would be to get a consensus from experts in the area such as through a relevant chat room.

You could also vote to reopen (requires 3k rep) and leave a comment as to why you are reopening (with the goal to close as a proper dupe) and include the link.

If all else fails, you can post here on meta as you have and see if others agree.

Comment: Ok, hmmm, thanks. "Though, looking at them, I'm not sure why it isn't a duplicate of the marked question" Because the question isn't about what `let` does, it's about what the `{ myProperty } = myObject` part does. The asker mentions `let` because they don't understand the part that comes after `let`. But that `let` is used is irrelevant to the not understood part. Damn, kinda hard to explain I guess. Which makes the wrong flag even more confusing, people just won't get the correct answer nor understand the syntax.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I didn't look it over too closely since that's not my best area but that's irrelevant to the answer for this post, really. I will remove that part

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer, I don't think I've got the rep to reopen though. And you just need to check the upvotes of the "This is not a duplicate" comments to see that, well, it's wrong. But thanks, now I know my options!

Comment: Couple more hundred points and you will have the privilege. Mods can't just go on upvotes though. And neither should others but I get your point

Comment: The correct dupe is listed, so it seems like reopening is not the right solution. Even if one or two people voted to close for the wrong reason, the correct close reason is still shown to the OP. In this case, it's second on the list, which is unfortunate.

Comment: @ssube sure but if you get with 5 3kers or one dupe hammer weilder (Either shouldn't be difficult through chat) then it can be reopened and closed right away with only the proper target. This seems to be the easiest way

Comment: I've voted to reopen now, and even the OP has chimed in agreeing that the first flag did not solve his problem. If there was any confusion left regarding that, it's gone. Now let's see if that works.